# JMeter automation using Maven - getting error while trying to run JMS files

Tags: maven, jmeter, jms

Below image shows an error after running JMS publisher via JMeter:
[image]
When my automation script runs it downloads JMeter in target folder, but I see `jndi.jar` and `jms.jar` missing in lib folder when JMeter is downloaded via automation script.

Could anyone please help me on how to solve the mentioned issue?

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for this. Just add the error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) you need to explicitly list all your dependency .jar libraries under `<testPlanLibraries>` section like:

```
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>USE LAST VERSION</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- HERE YOU NEED TO ADD YOUR JMS IMPLEMENTATION JARS-->
                    <testPlanLibraries>
                        <artifact>org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:5.15.2</artifact>
                        <artifact>org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:5.15.2</artifact>
                        <artifact>org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.15.2</artifact>
                    </testPlanLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This way JMeter Maven plugin will locate the .jar(s), download them and put them under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) so you will be able to use external libraries in your JMeter test

More information:

- [Adding Excluding libraries to from the classpath](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath)
- [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)

Comment: The error message in the question shows that following entry in `testPlanLibraries` is missing: `<artifact>com.sun.messaging.mq:fscontext:4.6-b01</artifact>`.